# Check if row exists in database table using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning SQLAlchemy and trying to check if a record exists in postgreSQL database using SQLAlchemy. There are many similar question here, but I am stuck. Here is my query:

```
ret = session.query(exists().where(COMPANY.name == 'MyTestCompany')).scalar()
```

"COMPANY" is table name , when I run it, I get error:

```
"NameError: name 'COMPANY' is not defined"
```

Should I somehow "register" COMPANY table as an object in current session or the problem lies somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are getting means there is no COMPANY variable defined in your python code.

Did you use any other ORM features? Usually you would need to create a `Company` **Model** to run a query like this. A model would look something like this:

```
class Company(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'company'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
```

Check out how they create a `User` model in this [tutorial](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html)

If you want to interact with SQL directly without ORM features you might be interested in [SQLAlchemy Core](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/)